# How do torrent clients ensure changes made to a file don't affect file transmission?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, torrent

Let's say there are two peers A and B. In oversimplified terms, when A requests a file from B, how does the torrent client on B ensure that changes made to the file by the user doesn't affect the file transmission? Does it copy the file to a temp folder before it starts sending chunks to the receiver peer or does it take a OS level write-lock of some sort and retains it till the transmission is completed?

Answer (score 2):

Files are hashed at creation time and the hashes are stored in the torrent file. The hashes are checked at download time.

You can find more details in the core [bittorrent protocol specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html).

What happens when a hash mismatch is detected is up to the implementation. Common approaches are to attempt to download the failed piece from a different peer and report hash failure statistics to the user. Optionally the sending peer may also check its own data and report that to its user, but the main intent of the specification is for the receiver to verify the data since it cannot trust the sender anyway.

Comment: What happens if the checksum doesn't match because the user changed the file after the torrent was created?

Comment: the reason for the data being corrupt (changed) is irrelevant. The bittorrent peer will most likely be banned from the swarm by any peer receiving the incorrect payload.